# CKEditor5: how to save the undo/redo stack when Multiple page switching

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm working on a note taking app with vue and ckeditor5. When I load a note, an editor instance is generated through a Vue component. However, when I switch to another page and then switch back, a new editor instance is generated instead of using the original one. This causes the undo/redo content in my editor to be cleared, making it impossible to use the undo/redo function.

Is there any way to reuse the original editor instance when switching pages? Or are there any other methods to preserve the undo/redo functionality when switching pages?

I have gone through the official documentation, but I couldn't find a way to implement it.. Or is there a better approach? any other methods or ideas to achieve this?

#### here is some code:

```js
        <ckeditor ref="editorRef" :editor="ckEditor" :config="ckConfig"
                  v-model="text"
                  @ready="onEditorReady"
                  @destroy="onEditorDestroy"/>

/********/
const pageStore = usePageStore()
const onEditorReady = (editor) => {
    pageStore.editors[id]=editor //save editor instance
}
```

I went through the source code and found the undo stack, but it doesn't seem to be of much use..

```js
editor.commands.get('undo')._stack
```